# Switch behavior on unicast packets when the destination is unknown

Tags: arp, switch

Please let me start by saying I am no network expert, I am a programmer who does a fair amount of L3/4 programming.

My question is that when a switch receives a packet with a destination MAC that is not found in its table arp table for whatever reason. What is the action performed? do they send an arp? send the packet on all output interfaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARP resolves IP addresses to MAC addresses. Switches don't ARP for traffic sent from one host to another host. As such you wouldn't find an entry for the destination host in the switch's ARP table unless the switch itself is trying to communicate with that destination host.

What you're looking for is the switch's MAC address table, which is it's MAC address to port table, which tells the switch which MAC address is accessible via which port.

In the case where the switch's MAC address table doesn't have an entry for the destination host the switch will flood/forward the frame to all ports. Note that I didn't use the term broadcast as this is not a broadcast. Unicast traffic is flooded in this scenario, broadcast traffic is broadcasted.

Answer (score 4):

The frame is forwarded out all interfaces except the interface on which it was received. MAC addresses are added to the address table when the switch receives a frame from that address.

Comment: In addition, Cisco will reference the Spanning-Tree Protocol.  Using show span (vlanid) will list the interfaces out which the packet will egress.

Answer (score 1):

Switch is a layer 2 device so it doesn't look for IP addresses. as joeqwerty said ARP helps you get the destination MAC address based on the destination IP address. When a switch doesn't have a destination MAC address in it's table it sends the frame to all its ports except the one it received the frame from.